# Extract a value between 2 different characters in R

Tags: r

If I have this:

```
2 (5.7%)
34 (8.9%)
```

How can I just extract what is in between the first ( and % (just the percentage number)?

```
5.7
8.9
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We may use `sub` to match the characters (`.*`) till the opening braces (`\\(`), capture the characters that are not `%` (`[^%]+`) as a group and replace with backreference of the captured group (`\\1`)

```
as.numeric(sub(".*\\(([^%]+).*", "\\1", str1))
[1] 5.7 8.9
```

---

Or use `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
as.numeric(str_extract(str1, "\\((.*)%", group = 1))
[1] 5.7 8.9
```

#### data

```
 str1 <- c("2 (5.7%)", "34 (8.9%)")
```

Answer (score 4):

To add to @akrun's answer, I've come across this issue before and ended up 'splitting up' a `mean (stdev)` or a `count (proportion%)` using this approach:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(result = c("2 (5.7%)",
                            "34 (8.9%)"))

df
#>      result
#> 1  2 (5.7%)
#> 2 34 (8.9%)

df %>%
  mutate(result = str_remove_all(result, "\\(|\\%\\)")) %>%
  separate(col = result, into = c("count", "proportion (%)"),
           sep = " ", convert = TRUE)
#>   count proportion (%)
#> 1     2            5.7
#> 2    34            8.9
```

This converts the columns into the 'correct' type:

```r
str(df)
#> 'data.frame':    2 obs. of  2 variables:
#>  $ count         : int  2 34
#>  $ proportion (%): num  5.7 8.9
```

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun:

```
library(readr)
library(stringr)
parse_number(str_replace(str1, paste(parse_number(str1), collapse = "|"), ''))
```

```
[1] 5.7 8.9
```

Comment: I like the approach (+1) but it looks like it needs to be tweaked @TarJae ("18.9" should be "8.9")

Comment: Thx. I changed the output. It was just because I used some different numbers to test!